# Boolean vectors of length $6$ formed by exactly three zero's and three one's

Tags: probability, statistics

The boolean vectors formed by exactly three zero's and three one's are

$\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}=400$

Is it wrong?

Comment: There are $2^6=64$ six-bit boolean vectors in total, so $400$ for a subset of them looks wrong

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is wrong.  Once you choose which three of the $6$ positions are $0$, the other three must be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: After you have chosen $3$ spots for the 0's, is there really anything more left to choose?